# Need ComboBoxes to automatically update

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

As you see in the above image, I have 2 ComboBoxes: "Select Dimension" and "List of possible values".

There are different dimensions the user can select and for each dimension there's a list of possible values. My code is partially working well. When I select a dimension for the 1st time the list of possible values appears properly.

**Problem:** When I select a different dimension, the list of possible values from the previous dimension still appears, instead of the values for the new selected dimension.

**Question:** Is there a way to solve this issue? So that when I switch between dimensions the lists of possible values also update.

#1: Function that gets the values from the Worksheet and adds them to the "List of possible values" combobox.

```
Public Function DimValuesSearch(strSearch As String)

Call loadWbVariables

Dim selectedDimension As String, possibleValue As String
Dim countValues As Long
Dim DimCell As Range

selectedDimension = frmSeg.seg_cbb_selDim.Value

Set DimCell = dtValWs.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch)

If selectedDimension = strSearch Then
    countValues = 0
    While dtValWs.Cells(4 + countValues, DimCell.Column) <> ""
        possibleValue = dtValWs.Cells(4 + countValues, DimCell.Column)
        frmSeg.seg_cbb_posVal.AddItem possibleValue
        countValues = countValues + 1
    Wend
End If

End Function
```

#2: I call the function using the different dimensions name. seg_cbb_selDim is the Dimension ComboBox.

```
Public Sub seg_cbb_selDim_Change()

' Functions that calls text dimensions
    ' Insert remaining dimensions

Call DimValuesSearch("Specialty Grouping")
Call DimValuesSearch("Primary Specialty")

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the `Change` event of your `Dimension` box to remove all items in the other combo and reload it with the desired items. • If that doesn't help please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure where I should insert the .Clear function in this situation. Can you explain a bit more? Is there any more code I need to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Change event of your `Dimension` box to remove all items in the other combo and reload it with the desired items.

It would look something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxDimensions_Change()
    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    LoadValuesIntoComboBox2

    Me.ComboBox3.Clear
    LoadValuesIntoComboBox3
End Sub


Public Sub LoadValuesIntoComboBox2()
    'your code to reload the desired data ino ComboBox2
End Sub

Public Sub LoadValuesIntoComboBox3()
    'your code to reload the desired data ino ComboBox3
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not working, it just clears everything :/

Comment: @soraia635 Of course you need to write the code that fills the combobox.

Comment: I use the call function I described above to do that. That's what is loading the Values ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

It was more simple than I though, I had to do a small change in the function above. Here's the new function:

```
Public Function DimValuesSearch(strSearch As String)

Call loadWbVariables

Dim selectedDimension As String, possibleValue As String
Dim countValues As Long
Dim DimCell As Range

selectedDimension = frmSeg.seg_cbb_selDim.Value

Set DimCell = dtValWs.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch)

If selectedDimension = strSearch Then
    countValues = 0
    frmSeg.seg_cbb_posVal.Clear        'Added this line here
    While dtValWs.Cells(4 + countValues, DimCell.Column) <> ""
        possibleValue = dtValWs.Cells(4 + countValues, DimCell.Column)
        frmSeg.seg_cbb_posVal.AddItem possibleValue
        countValues = countValues + 1
    Wend
End If

End Function
```